# How can I get the response JSON in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I want to make a chrome extension. I need to get the response JSON what can be seen in chrome's developer tools. It's a post by using fetch. Which API or javascript way can I use?

Comment: You can use the jquery AJAX for fetching the data from API

Comment: Assuming you want to intercept the request made by a site in the tab, you can use chrome.debugger API ([example](/a/29845219)) or hook XMLHttpRequest in the page context ([example](https://medium.com/better-programming/chrome-extension-intercepting-and-reading-the-body-of-http-requests-dd9ebdf2348b)).

Comment: What have you tried so far? Shouldn't a usual extension be written in JS, such that you can use the usual JS stuff?

Answer (score 0):

Just use [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) (another good alternative is [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios))

example:

```
async function getData() {
    try {
        const response = await fetch('https://your-res-website.com');
        const resJson = await response.json();

        return resJson;
    } catch (error) {
        console.warn('getData error', error);
    }

    return null;
}

getData().then(data => console.log(data));
```

[More info about Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

Comment: Thank you,but I already tried this way to fetch straightly.It doesn't work.It's a big company's website,when i tried this way,it always response'status 500'.But in chrome, it's normal,so i try to get the message in chrome.

Comment: Try to copy success response as fetch in chrome and update according success fetch https://i.imgur.com/GSVSiPp.png

Comment: fetch is the standard way to make requests in js env so it doesn't matter web, chrome or node (in node js you can find isomorphic fetch or axios)

Comment: well,I tested that the request payload could only be used two times,it means whether I can straightly get the chrome 's response,or after the chrome's response I get the first time 's payload